# Installing Arabic fonts on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fonts, arabic, arabic-support, polylang

I am trying to installed Arabic Fonts on my website. Following are the steps that I have already taken but the fonts are not being changed.

1. I uploaded the font files (Converted to webfonts and uploaded on website)
2. Installed the fonts:

```html
@font-face {
    font-family: 'jf_flatregular';
    src:url('fonts/jf-flat-regular-webfont.ttf') format('ttf'), 
 url('fonts/jf-flat-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/jf-flat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
html[lang="ar"] body {
    font-family: 'jf_flatregular';
}
```

The fonts of the website are changed to safe fonts i.e. Open Sans but my uploaded font is not being loaded on the website.

Notes:
1. Using Jupiter theme
2. Using Polylang plugin

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed another plugin "Use any font" and the applied that font on the Arabic website by the following code:

```
:lang(ar)   {
font-family: fontname !Important;
}
```

And done!

I found this solution, not sure if that should be done or not, but solved my issue. :)